# I am not able to pass Long as run time argument in Java program

Tags: java, arguments, long-integer

I am not able to pass `Long` as run time argument in Java program , I have tried `1L`, `1l`, `1.0L`, `1.0L` , but giving number format exception. Though its working fine for `1` but as per Java prog language `long` should be marked with suffix `L`. If I run this program for `float` and pass `1F` it's working fine.

```
public class Apple {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println(Long.parseLong(args[0]));
               /*System.out.println(Float.parseFloat(args[0]));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The expression `Long.parseLong(s)` invokes the method `parseLong` on its string argument `s`. This string had better look like `"1"` or `"123"` and *not* have an `L` at the end.

You are getting confused with the fact that *within Java source code*, long literals *are* marked with an `L`. In Java code we can write:

```
Long x = 1L;
```

because `1L` is part of Java source code; it is a long integer. However, just because we are allowed to write `1L` to represent a number in Java source code does *not* mean that `Long.parseLong` will understand the *string* `"1L"`. I can see why you might have assumed that, but that's not the way `Long.parseLong` works. It needs a plain old digit sequence, no `L`. That's just the way it is.

Comment: then why it is working fine for float , when i am passing 1F.

Comment: The reason is in Dragan's answer, which is more complete than mine, since it cites sources, and should be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

It is stated in javadoc for [`Long.parseLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29):

> Parses the string argument as a signed decimal `long`. The characters
>   in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first
>   character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' (\u002D') to indicate a
>   negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a
>   positive value. The resulting `long` value is returned, exactly as if
>   the argument and the radix `10` were given as arguments to the
>   `parseLong(java.lang.String, int)` method.
>
> Note that neither the character `L` ('\u004C') nor `l` ('\u006C') is
>   permitted to appear at the end of the string as a type indicator, as
>   would be permitted in Java programming language source code.

This is in contrast to `Float` where it is indicated in the javadoc that suffix is allowed. [`Float.parseFloat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat%28java.lang.String%29):

> Returns a new `float` initialized to the value represented by the
>   specified `String`, as performed by the `valueOf` method of class
>   `Float`.

[`Float.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) (excerpt):

> ... where *Sign*, *FloatingPointLiteral*, *HexNumeral*, *HexDigits*,
>   *SignedInteger* and *FloatTypeSuffix* are as defined in the lexical structure sections of *The Java™ Language Specification*, except that
>   underscores are not accepted between digits.